# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_hex}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I’m trying to render an object value in my React App, following a tutorial from udemy.com on ReactJS, web3 and Ethereum Solidity, I have done exactly what was done in this tutorial but I still get an error from my end.

What is wrong with my code?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    let myBalance = await ico.methods.myBalance().call({from: accounts[0]});

    this.setState({myBalance}); 
}
```

Any time I render `{this.state.myBalance}`, I expect to get 10000000000000000000000 rendered, but I instead get an error in ReactJS:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_hex}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

[image: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_hex}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]

Comment: What does myBalance actually look like?

Comment: are you trying to render `myBalance`? if so, then this is an object and react won't let you render objects. you can render the object as a string though `JSON.stringify(myBalance)`